# Why the FIFOs server cannot receive the data from client? use named-pipes

Tags: c, named-pipes

I just do a experiment of named-pipes in Ubuntu,but the server cannot receive the string which I input in the client,how can I solve it ? when I press Ctrl+C in the client,the sever can receive some characters.

Server

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<linux/stat.h>

#define FIFO_FILE "sampleFIFO"

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char readbuf[80];
    umask(0);
    mknod(FIFO_FILE,S_IFIFO|0666,0);
    while(1)
    {
        fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE,"r");
        fgets(readbuf,80,fp);
        printf("Received:%s\n",readbuf);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Client

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


#define FIFO_FILE "sampleFIFO"

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buf[80];
    if((fp = fopen(FIFO_FILE,"w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("error");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1)
    {
        memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
        fgets(buf,80,stdin);
        fputs(buf,fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code breaks the loop only when interrupted — you should test the return value from `fgets()` and use that to break the loop on EOF.

There's no guarantee with a FIFO as the output that `fp` is line buffered; you could add `fflush(fp)` after the `fputs()` call.

There's no need to use `memset()` as shown.

Since the client does not use its command line arguments, its `main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Your primary problem is the `fflush()` one, I believe; the others are more nearly cosmetic.

---

As was noted by [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg), the server is not completely problem free.

The server code in the question, although inefficient, will serve an arbitrary number of clients.  However, you really need nested loops.  The outer loop repeatedly opens the FIFO; the inner reads the contents of the FIFO.  When the inner loop reaches EOF, it is time to close the stream and reopen it.  Again, you need to test the return value from `fgets()` to ensure that you actually read data.  You should also consider how you make the server exit, and whether the server should remove the FIFO it creates.